# How do I restrict query results based on sub-results in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, conditional-statements

In CakePHP if I run the following find command

```
$this->Instructor->find('all');
```

the following is returned:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Instructor] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 3
                    [bio] => A billionaire playboy, industrialist and ingenious engineer, Tony Stark suffers a severe chest injury during a kidnapping in which his captors attempt to force him to build a weapon of mass destruction. He instead creates a powered suit of armor to save his life and escape captivity. He later uses the suit to protect the world as Iron Man.
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [first_name] => Tony
                    [last_name] => Stark
                    [asurite_user] => tstark
                    [asurite_id] => 
                    [password] => 
                    [email] => tstark@example.com
                    [created] => 2012-10-30 09:57:36
                    [modified] => 2012-10-30 09:57:36
                )

            [Course] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [slug] => beatles
                            [sln] => AAA001
                            [course_number] => 
                            [title] => The Beatles
                            [description] => This is a class about the Beatles.  If this were a real description, more information would be listed here.
                            [state] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [slug] => elvis
                            [sln] => AAA002
                            [course_number] => 
                            [title] => Elvis: The King of Rock
                            [description] => All about the king of rock and roll, Elvis Presley.
                            [state] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ...
```

There is a many-to-many relationship between "Instructor" and "Course". How can I filter the results based on the "Course"s each "Instructor" belongs to?  I tried the following without success:

```
$instructors = $this->Instructor->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Course.id' = 2)
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to restrict your parent item based on conditions against your child item, you can either do your main query through the child model instead of the main model, and [contain()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) the rest, or use MySQL Joins - available in CakePHP via [joins()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables).

Comment: Adding a "joins" to the find options is exactly what I needed to do.  It was actually very similar to the example they give at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You need to (re)bind the associations for your Instructor model with hasOne and use these settings:

```
'CoursesInstructor' => array(
    'className' => 'CoursesInstructor',
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'conditions' => 'Instructor.id = CoursesInstructor.id'),
'Course' => array(
    'className' => 'Course',
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'conditions' => 'CoursesInstructor.course_id = Course.id');
```

This will generate the correct SQL with the required joins and your conditions will work.

Comment: That seems counter-intuitive.  The hasAndBelongsToMany relationship exists for exactly the purpose I'm describing (Courses can have multiple instructors and instructors can have multiple courses).